# Link to youtube video with start and stop

Tags: html, video, hyperlink, youtube, segment

Some years ago I used to create a link to insert in a pdf which would run a segment of a youtube video as follows:
http://www.youtube.com/v/[video_id]&start=[start_at_second]&end=[end_at_second]&version=3

now with the move to HTML5 it seems the new format should be:
https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=IPQQ8yWpH9c&start=10&end=20&autoplay=0

However I am unable to make either workl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In URL 1 you are forgetting the `?` for the query string. It should be :

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/[video_id]?start=[start_at_second]&end=[end_at_second]&version=3
```

Notice the `?` before start (instead of the `&` you had).

The second one you don't need the `watch?v=`, it should be:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/IPQQ8yWpH9c?start=10&end=20&autoplay=0
```